# Data sending between js file and esp32 sketch

Tags: javascript, web, esp32

I want to use an esp32 as a web server to display information within a browser.
I have an esp32 sketch that processes some data from sensors and i want to stream them into the js file so that i can display them on the web page as a graph that updates periodically.
My problem is that no matter what i try, i just can't figure out how to funnel the data between the two files.
Any help, please?
Thanks for all responses in advance!

Comment: Hi Jakub, welcome to SO. Please note that we would need to see your existing code (as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to be of use.

Answer (score 1):

sorry for posting an answer, i don't have the required level to comment

first, I am sorry to tell you that even if you update the javascript file in real time, its content will not load on the web.

but you can send the updated sensor data via WebSocket server to the javascript client and then update your interface

this is a little WS library i have done before, its simple but functional

```
export const ws = (url) => {
    let ws = null
    let connectListeners = []
    let receiveListeners = []
    let retryCount = 1
    const api = {
        connect(newUrl, attemps = -1) {
            if (ws != null) {
                ws.onmessage = null
                ws.onerror = null
                ws.onclose = null
                ws.onopen = null
            }
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                ws = new WebSocket(newUrl || url)
                ws.onopen = (e) => {
                    connectListeners.forEach(cbk => {
                        cbk(e)
                    })
                    resolve(api)
                }
                ws.onmessage = (e) => {
                    let data = e.data
                    try {
                        data = JSON.parse(data)
                    } catch (e) {}

                    receiveListeners.forEach(cbk => {
                        cbk(data)
                    })
                }
                ws.onerror = (e) => {
                    if (attemps > 0 && retryCount < attemps) {
                        retryCount++
                        api.connect(newUrl, attemps)
                    } else if (attemps < 0) {
                        api.connect(newUrl, attemps)
                    } else {
                        reject(e)
                    }
                }
            })
        },
        onconnect(e) {
            connectListeners.push(e)
        },
        onreceive(e) {
            receiveListeners.push(e)
        },
        send(data) {
            if (ws.readyState == WebSocket.OPEN) {
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(data))
            }
            return this;
        },
        close(forced = false) {
            if (forced) {
                this.connect()
            } else {
                ws.close()
            }
            return this;
        }
    }
    return api;
}
```

and then you can use it as follow

```
const wsClient = ws('ws://your-esp32-ip/')
wsClient.onreceive(function(data){
    console.log(data)
})
wsClient.connect() // you can pass a new connection url and number of connection attemps
```